# InfoPath 2010 - Email - How to send FROM a specified email account

Tags: email, submit, infopath, sender

I have an infopath form that generates and email.  I'd like to know if it's possible to change the "From" field of the email to send from a generic shared mailbox instead of the message coming from my personal account.

Is this possible to do WITHOUT code using only the built in InfoPath 2010 controls/rules, or will there have to be custom coding involved?

I have tried Googling this for hours, but unfortunately, searching with the word "from" yields far too many unrelated results.  And I've tried every permutation of my search terms as I can think of.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page discusses the same issue. http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/9176/34609.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So it seems the answer to my question is no. It cannot be done out of the box, which makes me sad.  Guess it's time to brush up on my coding skills. :-)